# curl_easy_perform returns -1 when server is not reachable

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

When i am trying to do some HTTP_POST,HTTP_DELETE operation to a unreachable server the return code is sometimes coming as -1.Because of that my application is crashing.

Here is my sample code.

My application code is in c++ where i am reading the response and response header also.

```
  lCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
                                      HttpClientImplCurl::recvFunctionHeader);

    if (lCode != CURLE_OK) {
        LOG(LOG_CRIT, "CURL failure: curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION returned %d\n", lCode);
        curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);
        errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);
        return http_code;

    }


    lCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER,
                                      &readResHeaderBuffer);

    if (lCode != CURLE_OK) {
        LOG(LOG_CRIT, "CURL failure: curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER returned %d\n", lCode);
        curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);
        errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);
        return http_code;

    }

        lCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,
                             HttpClientImplCurl::recvFunction);

    if (lCode != CURLE_OK) {
        LOG(LOG_CRIT, "CURL failure: curl_easy_setopt WRITEFUNCTION returned %d\n", lCode);
        curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);
        errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);
        return http_code;

    }

    lCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,
                             &readResBuffer);

    if (lCode != CURLE_OK) {
        LOG(LOG_CRIT, "CURL failure: curl_easy_setopt WRITEDATA returned %d\n", lCode);
        curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);
        errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);
        return http_code;

    }

    lCode = curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE"); /* !!! */

    if (lCode != CURLE_OK) {
        LOG(LOG_CRIT, "CURL failure: curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST returned %d\n", lCode);
        curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);
        errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);
        return http_code;

    }

    lCode =  curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, aInRemovedata.getBuffer()); /* data goes here */

    if (lCode != CURLE_OK) {
        LOG(LOG_CRIT, "CURL failure: curl_easy_setopt CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  returned %d\n", lCode);
        curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);
        errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);
        return http_code;

    }

lCode = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);


    if (lCode != CURLE_OK) {
        LOG(LOG_CRIT, "CURL failure: curl_easy_perform returned %d\n", lCode);
        curl_slist_free_all(lHeaders);
        errorBuff = curl_easy_strerror(lCode);---->my doubt is when i am geting "-1", this line is caused the crash.
        return http_code;
    }
```

And my callback are as follows,

```
  size_t
HttpClientImplCurl::recvFunctionHeader(void *aInBuf, size_t aInSize,
                                size_t aInNmemb, void* aInUserp)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "curl error: too small buffer in recv2\n");
    ((std::string*)aInUserp)->append((char*)aInBuf, aInSize * aInNmemb);
    return aInSize * aInNmemb;
}


// Private static callback
size_t
HttpClientImplCurl::recvFunction(void *aInBuf, size_t aInSize,
                                size_t aInNmemb, void* aInUserp)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "curl error: too small buffer in recv1\n");
    ((std::string*)aInUserp)->append((char*)aInBuf, aInSize * aInNmemb);
    return aInSize * aInNmemb;
}
```

Please help me on this, why we are getting occasionally "-1" in place of "28".

Here is the function signature, where errorBuf is coming as a parameter

```
 int
HttpClientImplCurl::put(const HttpClient& aInClient,const base::Buffer& aInPutdata,
                          base::Buffer& aOutRecvBuf,base::Buffer&  aOutRecvHeaderBuf,const char*& errorBuff)
```

Comment: How is `errorBuff` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER and CURLOPT_VERBOSE to get more information on why the value returned by curl_easy_perform is -1.